# Inner shadow scroll view

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to draw an inner shadow in a scroll view. The scroll view contains small image views, and I need to put a shadow like the attached image, but without border in the layer. How can I do it?

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an overlay png with transparency. Put it in an ImageView and add it in scroll view's superView (So you need a regular view controller as the super view that contains the scroll view)

Comment: So the hierachy should be: View Controller - UIView - UIImageView (with  overlay png) - UIScrollView ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes but the UIImageView - UIScrollView part can be confusing. Note that the UIImageView does not contain the scroll view. UIView contains both - but the ImageView is higher in the hierarchy (than the scrollView).